# jQuery lightbox not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, lightbox

I am using this [LightBox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) on http://sbc.mojopin.co.uk/portfolio.php and just cannot get it to work. I have included all the files required, and more, including the LightBox plugin js files and its css file.

The function seems to get to the line:

```
$.fn.lightBox = function(settings)
```

then it jumps right to the end. I believe I have the correct js for the page but it won't work correctly.

For those that don't want to click through the link to see the problem, basically when I click on the thumb image it just goes to the image instead of showing it in the lightbox. I'm sure it's a fairly simple problem, but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you have a spelling mistake in your jQuery selector: http://sbc.mojopin.co.uk/sbc.js

```
$('#contemporyGallery a').lightBox();
```

Should be:

```
$('#contemporaryGallery a').lightBox();
```

Cheers!

Comment: Oh dear, I have sat for half an hour staring at this, I knew it had to be something stupid! Cheers!

Comment: No worries! It's always good to have another pair of eyes to take a look at the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
$('#contemporyGallery a').lightBox();
```

with

```
$('#contemporaryGallery a').lightBox();
```

Also note that you have included multiple lightbox scripts, you only need *.min.js

Comment: Oh I know about the lightbox scripts, I was adding them to see if it helped! Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

How about attaching your lightbox to a class on each image like so..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.lightbox').lightBox(); // Select all links in object with gallery ID
});
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. But it still makes sense as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

silly mistake: replacing (you spelled `contemporyGallery` wrong :)  )

`$('#contemporyGallery a').lightBox();`

with

`$('#contemporaryGallery a').lightBox();`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you made a typo in your jQuery selector:

This:

```
$('#contemporyGallery a').lightBox();
```

Should be:

```
$('#contemporaryGallery a').lightBox();
```

To avoid such mistakes in the future use an [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) such as [Aptana Studio 3](http://aptana.com/products/studio3) which will inform you of errors like these (and other ones).